# JavaFX Button onAction won't open selected FXML view

Tags: javafx, controller

I'm stuck with the 'menu screen' for a while.

when I click ACTIVATED CUSTOMER PANEL, it wont open the CustomerDisplay.fxml

[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4dhr.png)

Below is my codes;

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

protected Parent content;
private Stage primaryStage;
private Stage secondStage;
private CustomerController custCtrl;
private MaintainerController mntnCtrl;
private MachineryController machCtrl;
private String fxml="";
public static MainApp instance;

public MainApp () {
    instance=this;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    launch(args);
}

public static MainApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    initializePanel();
    Scene scene = new Scene(content);

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void initializePanel() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/SimulatorDisplay.fxml"));
    content = loader.load();        
}

public void openCustomerPanel() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/CustomerDisplay.fxml"));
    content = loader.load(); 
}

public void openMaintainerPanel() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/MaintainerDisplay.fxml"));
    content = loader.load();        
}

public void openMachineryPanel() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/MachineryDisplay.fxml"));
    content = loader.load();        
}
```

}

```
public class SimulatorController implements Initializable{{
.
.
.
    @FXML
    public void clickCustomer (ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        log.info("Starting Customer Panel");
        MainApp.getInstance().openCustomerPanel()**;
    }
}
```

It prints log.info("Starting Customer Panel") but I couldn't see any new window.
I want to know how we can click a button on main screen, and display new window. The main screen remain open unless we close it. Do we need to define new Stage?

Comment: Your methods `openXXXPanel` just load an FXML file and assign the object corresponding to the root element to the variable `content`, but they don't do anything with the new content. You need to either set the root of the current scene to `content` (if you want to use the existing window), or create a new `Stage` (if you want a new window).

Comment: I create secondary stage, but it keep popup main screen over main screen when clicked

Comment: ok, now I got it. Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on James_D's comment;
Here is the working codes:

```
        public class MainApp extends Application {

        public static MainApp instance;
        private Stage secondaryStage;
    .
    .
    .

        public void openCustomerPanel() throws IOException{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            secondaryStage= new Stage();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/CustomerDisplay.fxml"));
            content = loader.load(); 
            Scene scene = new Scene(content);
            secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
            secondaryStage.show();
        }
    }
```